# When I draw a rectangle, doesn't appear?

Tags: inkscape

Whenever I try to draw a rectangle, nothing appear and even when I close Inkscape and try again, the same thing happens.
[image: This is what it looks like]

Answer (score 5):

The fill indicator at the bottom left of your screenshot shows that you have set the Alpha Channel of the fill to 0 - which means it is fully transparent. You may have done this accidentally.

[image]

You can easily fix this by double clicking on the fill indicator (circled red above) to open up the Fill panel.

In the fill panel, you can click and drag the alpha channel slider, or type in a new value.

[image]

If it annoys you that Inkscape always remembers the last setting/colour used for the Rectangle Tool, you can change that behaviour in the preferences. You can set it to "This tools own style".

[image]

Comment: I do this *all the freaking time*, especially with opacity. I didn't know there was a preference for this--thanks!

Comment: My Fill and Stroke says N/A. So I can't change them and having this same problem. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Azurespot - this isn't a chat forum.  If you are having a problem, you should ask a new question.

Comment: So, I guess you don't know. Better to have skipped a comment. It's related, so it felt like it belonged here. Obviously this is not a chat forum.